# Delphi 7 Occasional deadlock changing TLabel.Font.Style from IdHTTPListener event

Tags: delphi, user-interface, thread-safety, deadlock, indy

Wondered if anyone could help with a really tricky sporadic (not consistently reproducible) issue - possibly to do with threads. I'm in Delphi 7 (it's old code...), running an IdHttpListener (Indy). Code below is copied from a large cumbersome app - but hopefully enough to explain. An incoming HTTP request runs the following event - where web_lock is a TCriticalSection I define at the top. I do it in a critical section as the web requests causes changes that I need to be atomic.

```
procedure TFWebServer.WebServerCommandGet(Thread: TIdPeerThread;
  RequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; ResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);

var S,PageString : string;

begin
  web_lock.Acquire;
  PageString:=' ';
  if (copy(RequestInfo.Document,1,15)='/_Request_Part_') then begin
    s:=copy(RequestInfo.Document,16,length(RequestInfo.Document));
    FMainGui.doFunction(s);
    PageString:='OK';
  end; // Lots more else cases here...
  ResponseInfo.ContentType:='text/plain';
  ResponseInfo.ResponseNo:=200;
  ResponseInfo.ContentStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  ResponseInfo.ContentStream.Write(PageString[1],length(PageString)*
    sizeof(PageString[1]));
  ResponseInfo.ContentLength:=length(PageString)*sizeof(PageString[1]);
  web_lock.Release;
end;
```

and then, my FMainGui.doFunction(s) does something like this:-

```
procedure doFunction(s : String);
var i,j : integer;
begin
  i:=strtoint(s); 
  for j:=1 to Pages do begin // Pages is dynamic - but correctly set
    if (j=i) then // Pagelabs[j] is always a visible TLabel
      Pagelabs[j].Font.Style:=[fsBold]
      else Pagelabs[j].Font.Style:=[];
  end;
end;
```

Bit simplified - Pagelabs is a set of dynamically created TLabels that I display on a page, and the one you've selected using the web request gets made bold.

THE PROBLEM: Occasionally, and unpredictably, I get some kind of deadlock dealing with the web request - it just freezes, with circular swirly mouse pointer, and doesn't recover. If I'm debugging it in Delphi, the call stack is empty, and I can only step through the assembly code - afraid I'm not up to working what that means! I tracked it down to the Pagelabs[j].Font.Style:=[fsBold] line above, by writing one line text files between every single line of code... so while the error was sporadic, when it did occur, it was always that line it locked up on.

I appreciate this is a snippet of a large app, but is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong? Eg - should it be safe to change GUI properties from a thread triggered by the HTTP Listener? Or is there something different I should be doing?

Any ideas much appreciated,
Thanks,
Wes

Comment: I assume you mean `i := StrToInt(s);`, not `IntToStr(s)'` and `doFunction(const s: string)`. Please post compilable code

Comment: Apologies - I was trying to type a minimal illustration from over 22k lines, and made a couple of trivial typos in doing so. I'll edit my original; the essence of the question had already been answered below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot manipulate UI controls from worker threads, only from the main GUI thread!

You have two options:

You may block your HTTP threads and temporary switch to main thread by `TThread.Synchronize()` procedure. Like in this example:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/Synchronize_(Delphi)

You may prefer delayed out-of-sync execution via

- Windows messages ( use PostMessage and avoid SendMessage )http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/howto_send_custom_window_message.htm
- AsyncCall library http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/
- thread-queues approach with something like OmniThreadsLibrary

First option might slow you down, for any long processing in the GUI thread would also freeze your HTTP handlers.

Second options would require making a "snapshot" copy of any required data and passing it along with the deferred call request ( as the VCL update code might be executed at any random time AFTER (or during) the HTTP handler (or several HTTP handlers). It would be normal when several HTTP handlers would request GUI updates and you would have to check which of them passed the most recent data and skip other requests for example.

Comment: Great - so going with the first option: call thread.synchronize(doFunction) - (where thread is an argument passed by the event call to WebServerCommandGet) - and arrange for the argument I was sending to doFunction to be visible to it some other way...

Comment: in your code snippet there is another problem... What if `i:=inttostr(s);` throws an exception...

Comment: But yes, if you only need to show last received number, then better have some GUI-global property... So last one to change it would be the value displayed.  And only request re-draw if you really changed its value, if the value is the same again - no point to do it I think.
PS. from personal experience - skip the redraw threads altogether. If you would redraw 30 times per second human eye would not read it. Just set TTimer onto the form with for example 500ms rate. Changing S-value would enable it. Entering OnTimer event would disable the timer and redraw GUI. Redraw throttling for free.

Comment: That inttostr is actually a typo - should be strtoint! But you knew what I meant somehow! The way it works, 's' is guaranteed to contain an integer at that point, so I've been a bit minimal (or lazy!) perhaps. I hadn't thought about the redraw - it doesn't need to be very fast at all; it's bringing up a page of song lyrics on a server, requested from an android app, so within a second is fine. What if I call "invalidate" on the labels that get changed?

Comment: @WesHinsley invalidate is called automatically when you change fonts. The issue is that Windows would repaint window as fast as it can, which can easily consume 100% of CPU core and flicker faster than a person can read. I think you better throttle it down. And fixed FPS by TTimer is IMHO the easiest way to achieve it. // exceptions in async mt code might be hell. Any stupid mistake and you would generate endless stream of StrToInt exceptions gaster than human can close messageboxes. Up to you, but i'd better guarded against them.