# NetShareEnum not displaying shares correctly

Tags: delphi

I'm developing a project to help me managing my remote network, as I need some very specific features I decided to code it.

I connect to the remote computers using [WNetAddConnection2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx) and this part is working. But now I try to list all the shares (ADMIN$, C$, IPC$, and any shared folders) using the [NetShareEnum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/bb525387(v=vs.85).aspx) function. I relied on this function and not on *WNetEnumResource* because I found more examples working with NetShareEnum, and it's working better for me. The problem is that my implementation of NetShareEnum is listing only some type of folders (looks like only folders that are shared but I have no access). **It doesn't list normal folders (where I have access), ADMIN$, C$, IPC$, or anything else. Only shared folders that I'm without rights to access.**

I still not sure if the behavior is the same on all servers, but the ones I tested it was. So far what I have is:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  HostFile: TStringList;
  iHost: integer;

type
  SharesThread = class(TThread)
  strict private
    IPAddress: String;
    function Authenticate: bool;
    procedure EnumShares(RemoteName: PWChar);
  protected
    constructor Create(const IPv4: string);
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

type
  _SHARE_INFO_502         =  packed record
     shi502_netname:      PWideChar;
     shi502_type:         DWORD;
     shi502_remark:       PWideChar;
     shi502_permissions:  DWORD;
     shi502_max_uses:     DWORD;
     shi502_current_uses: DWORD;
     shi502_path:         LPWSTR;
     shi502_passwd:       LPWSTR;
     shi502_reserved:     DWORD;
     shi502_security_dsc: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
  end;
  SHARE_INFO_502          =  _SHARE_INFO_502;
  PSHARE_INFO_502         =  ^SHARE_INFO_502;
  LPSHARE_INFO_502        =  PSHARE_INFO_502;
  TShareInfo502           =  SHARE_INFO_502;
  PShareInfo502           =  PSHARE_INFO_502;

type
  TShareInfo502Array      =  Array [0..MaxWord] of TShareInfo502;
  PShareInfo502Array      =  ^TShareInfo502Array;

function NetApiBufferFree(buffer: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall; external 'netapi32.dll';

function NetShareEnum(servername: PWideChar;
                        level: DWORD;
                        bufptr: PByteArray;
                        prefmaxlen: DWORD;
                        entriesread: PDWORD;
                        totalentries: PDWORD;
                        resume_handle: PDWORD): DWORD; stdcall; external 'netapi32.dll';

implementation

const
  NERR_Success          =      0;
  MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH  =      DWORD( -1 );

procedure StartThreads;
var
  CurrentIP: string;
begin
  if (iHost < HostFile.Count) then
  begin
    CurrentIP:= HostFile.Strings[iHost];
    inc(iHost);
    SharesThread.Create(CurrentIP);
  end
  else
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('finished');
end;

constructor SharesThread.Create(const IPv4: string);
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  FreeOnTerminate:= true;
  IPAddress:= IPv4;
end;

function SharesThread.Authenticate;
var
  lpNetResource: TNetResource;
  myres: cardinal;
begin
  with lpNetResource do
  begin
    dwType := RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
    lpLocalName := nil;
    lpProvider := nil;
    lpRemoteName:= PChar('\\'+IPAddress);
  end;
  myres := WNetAddConnection2(lpNetResource, PChar('123456'), PChar('BlackNote'), 0);
  if ( myres = NO_ERROR ) then
  begin
    Result:= true;
    EnumShares(lpNetResource.lpRemoteName);
  end
  else
  begin
    Result:= false;
  end;
end;

procedure SharesThread.EnumShares(RemoteName: PWChar);
var
  p: PShareInfo502Array;
  res, er, tr, resume, i: DWORD;
begin
  repeat
    res:=NetShareEnum(RemoteName, 502, @p, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, @er, @tr, @resume);
    if (res = ERROR_SUCCESS) or (res = ERROR_MORE_DATA) then
    begin
      for i:=1 to Pred(er) do
      begin
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(String(p^[i].shi502_netname));
      end;
      NetApiBufferFree(p);
    end;
  until (res <> ERROR_MORE_DATA);
end;

procedure SharesThread.Execute;
begin
  if Authenticate then
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(IPAddress + '=' + 'Listed shares above')
end;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HostFile:= TStringList.Create;
  HostFile.LoadFromFile('Hosts.txt');
  iHost:= 0;
  StartThreads;
end;
end.
```

I can post my IP address here to you try this project, but not sure if this is under the rules. Anyway, is something wrong with this code?

Comment: Pretty hard to know what's going wrong. Could be the interop, or it could be that you are using the API incorrectly. If I were you I'd remove interop from the equation, and do the initial development in C++ using the Windows header files. That way you would know that the interop was not the problem. For instance, I've no idea why you decided that the record should be packed. Could that be the problem? Maybe. Maybe not. Remove those potential failure points from the equation.

Comment: Interop I think means calling the function from external DLL in Delphi?
I think so... Problem is that I know 0 C++... I think to remove those potential failure, I could use the WNetEnumResource, but no success so far on this.

Comment: `for i:=1 to Pred(er) do` - why do you skip the first element, which is #0 ?

Comment: `502: ...Shares from different scopes are not returned` 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb525387.aspx

Comment: PS: implementing your own API translation is really funy sometimes. But maybe you could make use of read-made JEDI API lib and Windows Security project

Comment: Yeah, I did the changes you said, `for i:=0 to er - 1 do` and implemented `ShareInfo2` instead of 502... I got a few more results, but still missing many folders on many servers...

Comment: By interop I mean your header translations.  You might have got them wrong.  I doubt that the record really is packed.  That's for sure a problem on x64.  But it's just an area of doubt.  Trying to work with gnarly areas of Win32 without learning basic C++ is a very bad idea in my view.  All the best example code is in C++.  You are intentionally tying your hands behind your back.  Only knowing one language, and such a minority one, is a real handicap.  You'll be much better equipped if you learnt enough C++ to use somebody else's example code to access this API.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan all fields in the record seem to be 4-bytes sized, so the "packed" should make zero difference in this particular case

Comment: @LessStress what about 503 mode ? Maybe you can also use WMI, dunno

Answer (score 0):

I think you have BAD multithreading issues.

First of all, check if the very API you use is thread-safe.
I did not found this particular information, but http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/8e7756aee43ed65a.htm

Maybe you just can not call that function from different threads at the same time.

Second: all hundreds of your threads do `Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(String(p^[i].shi502_netname))` - that is VERY wrong.

1. You CAN NOT access GUI objects from threads. CAN NOT. Period.
   See [Delphi 7 Occasional deadlock changing TLabel.Font.Style from IdHTTPListener event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119812/) for example.

The very process of loading form from DFM-resource, initializing it, creating Windows and Delphi objects and binding them, together is complex.
When at the same time hundreds of threads are crashing into half-created from and updating half-created MEMO they literally do destroy actions of one another.

Basically you told us that Windows did not returned you all the shares - but what you mean is that half-created TMemo abused by hundreds of threads does not show you all the shares. That is not the same, that might mean Windows work badly, but it also might mean Windows works ok, but you fail to put all the results into VCL GUI. You have to ensure what exactly happened.

Try getting shares
  1.1  only in one single thread!
  1.2  and that should be MAIN thread, not extra ones.
  1.3  and you only should start it after the form is created - for example from some button click event.

And check if there is the difference.

2. You should not add data by one line to the memo - it is VERY slow.

Make a simple test.

```
uses Hourglass; // http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/posts/tag/delticshourglass
const cMax = 10000;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click( Sender: TObject );
var sl: TStrings; i: integer; t: cardinal;
begin 
  HourglassOn();
  t := GetTickCount();
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 1 to cMax do
      sl.Add(IntToStr(i));
    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    Memo1.Lines.AddStrings(sl);
  finally
    sl.Destroy; 
  end;
  t := GetTickCount - t;
  ShowMessage('It took ' + IntoToStr(t) + '/1000 seconds');
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click( Sender: TObject );
var i: integer; t: cardinal;
begin 
  HourglassOn();
  t := GetTickCount();
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  for i := 1 to cMax do begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i));

    // giving Windows chance to repaint the memo
    // simulating access from extra threads
    // when main thread is free to repaint forms time and again
    Application.ProcessMessages; 
  end;

  t := GetTickCount - t;
  ShowMessage('It took ' + IntoToStr(t) + '/1000 seconds');
end;
```

So a little draft to test your issues might be like this

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllLines
- http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2010/06/omnithreadlibrary-20-sneak-preview-1.html
- http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2010/11/multistage-processes-with.html
- http://otl.17slon.com/book/chap04.html#highlevel-pipeline

Just a draft for you to look into generic approach

```
const WM_EnumEnded = WM_USER + 1;

type TFrom1 = class(TForm)
       Memo1: TMemo;
       Button1: TButton;
       Button2: TButton;
     ....
     public
       var Enums: iOmniBlockingCollection;
       procedure StartEnum( const SingleThread: boolean );
       procedure ShowResults( var m: TMessage); message WM_EnumEnded;
     .....


procedure TFrom1.StartEnum( const SingleThread: boolean );
var hosts: TStringDynArray; // TArray<string>, array of string....
    Source: IOmniBlockingCollection;
    iWorker: IOmniParallelLoop<T>; // variable only needed for if-then-else
begin
  hosts := TFile.ReadAllLines('hosts.txt');
  Self.Enums := TOmniBlockingCollection.Create; // Results accumulator
  Source := TOmniBlockingCollection.Create;
  Source.Add( TOmniValue.FromArray<string>(hosts) );

  iWorker := Parallel.ForEach<string>( Source ).NoWait().OnStop(
     procedure begin PostMessage( Self.Handle, WM_EnumEnded, 0, 0) end
  );
  if SingleThread then iWorker := iWorker.NumTasks(1);

  iWorker.Execute(
    procedure(const value: String) 
    var i: integer;
    begin 
       ....
        res:=NetShareEnum(RemoteName, 502  { 503 better ?? } ... );
       ....
         Self.Enums.Add( TOmniValue(String(p^[i].shi502_netname)) ); 
       ...
    end;
  );
end;

procedure TFrom1.ShowResults( var m: TMessage );
var sa: TArray<String>;
begin
  Self.Enums.CompleteAdding;
  sa := TOmniblockingCollection.ToArray<string>( Self.Enums );
  Memo1.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.AddStrings( sa );
end;

procedure TFrom1.Button1Click(sender: Tobject);
begin
  StartEnum( True );
end;

procedure TFrom1.Button2Click(sender: Tobject);
begin
  StartEnum( False );
end;
```