# Thread update GUI

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I've used the Delphi many years ago, I remember that in version 7 and even then I did not have much knowledge, I worked with C++ since then and I am currently working in a company using Delphi XE10 and realized that searching I found a lot of random things of difference versions and that makes me a little confused.

I'm playing with threads and I wanted to update the GUI and searching I found the `Synchronize` and the way in which it works shows the impact it has on performance, you can notice the application freezing.

I was wondering if there is a smoother way to handle this, something like events, notifications or whatever?

@edit

```
unit WriterThreadUnit;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, Unit1;

type
  TWriterThread = class(TThread)
  private
    linesToPrint: integer;
    fileDirectory: string;
    function generateFilename(): string;
    procedure write();
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create
    (
      const createSuspended: boolean;
      const linesToPrint: integer;
      fileDirectory: string
    );
  end;

implementation

{ TWriterThread }

constructor TWriterThread.Create
(
  const createSuspended: boolean;
  const linesToPrint: integer;
  fileDirectory: string
);
begin
  Self.linesToPrint    := linesToPrint;
  Self.fileDirectory   := fileDirectory;
  Self.FreeOnTerminate := true;

  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

procedure TWriterThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;

  write;
end;

function TWriterThread.generateFilename: string;
begin
  Result := Format('%s\%s_total_lines_%d.txt',
    [
      Self.fileDirectory,
      FormatDateTime('hh-mm-ss-zzz', Now),
      self.linesToPrint
    ]
  );
end;

procedure TWriterThread.write;
var
  fileLines: TStringList;
  i: integer;
  filename: string;
begin
  fileLines := TStringList.Create;
  filename := generateFilename;

  try
    for I := 1 to Self.linesToPrint do
    begin

      Synchronize(
        procedure
        begin
          Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Writing: ' + IntToStr(I) + ' to ' + generateFilename);
        end
      );

      fileLines.Add(Format('Line number: %d', [i]));
      Sleep(1);
    end;

    fileLines.SaveToFile(filename);
  finally
    fileLines.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Probably you are using `Synchronize` wrong. "Synced" procedure has to work a little - just update interface in main thread. Show you code, please. Of course, there are many other ways, with events etc.

Comment: @MBo Edited with the thread code.

Comment: I'm curious why you are updating the memo with each iteration?  This makes the thread pointless.. keep the thread working in the background, and update as little as possible.

Comment: @JohnEasley - As I said, I'm just messing around and trying to learn how thread works in Delphi. I used to do the same in Qt-C++ and it works normally without freezing. They use events called signals and slots.

Comment: Your code updates too fast. You don't have to add every single line one at a time; you can add them several en masse. You could also use `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` on the memo, which would speed things drastically. Synchronize itself is not slow; the code you're synchronizing is poor. "I bought a Ferrari, and I'm disappointed. It's not very fast." Well, how do you drive it? "I go to and from my office on city streets, and I never shift it out of first gear. It's a really bad car."

Comment: @KenWhite - I'm going to make a few tests. But the question remains, is there other alternatives like events or notifications?

Comment: Of course. But you should work first on understanding (and correcting) the code you have now, before you worry about other ways to do things. How else will you be able to decide whether the other method is an improvement? Until you understand that cars have more than one gear, and there are other roads besides city streets, how can you decide which car is faster or better? Using an event or notification isn't going to make poorly written UI code perform better; it's just going to introduce another level of complexity.

Comment: @KenWhite - Thank you, I'll be understanding and fixing this one first and looking for other solutions and continue.

Comment: @daitouvi, you must realize that, when calling synchronize the worker thread needs to wait for the main thread to execute your GUI update code. A better way is avoid Synchronize at all costs and inform the GUI thread via windows messaging (ie PostMessage)

Comment: Switch from a synchronised push model to an asynchronous pull model.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not wrong - it just spends a lot of time in many, many small VCL GUI updates.

I suspect that Memo redrawing is not fast procedure (note `BeginUpdate/EndUpdate` influence when Memo is filled with thousands of strings line-by-line). So make sync calls as seldom as possible (sending string packs, if needed). Indeed, user is not capable to see 1000 updates in second.

Comment: I don't know why but I still think that `Synchronize` makes the application to freeze. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: I'm asking for an alternative because imagine if I'm doing some process like using stream and I need to update a progress bar or something, I don't think that `Synchronize` will help much. I tried the samples that comes with Delphi and there is one for HTTP download and it freezes the GUI, it is noticeable.

Comment: The problem is that you are calling Synchronize for each loop cycle. This could depending on the rest of your loop cycle result in more than 1000 calls of the Synchronize in order to update the UI of your application. But because UI updating is to slow this creates your applications bottleneck. In fact even if updating of UI would be much faster trying to update it more often that your screen can refresh is just waste of processing resources. So try to lower the amount of times the synchronize is called by calling it every 10 or perhaps even better every 100 loop cycles instead.

Comment: Any method that updates UI too frequently, will cause performance degradation. Sometimes methods other that `synchronize` would perform better - but not in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just try to fix your current code as others said?
You should not update GUI thousand of times per second, you do realize that this does not make any sense? However, even your example is working without freezing the GUI on my machine (and my machine is old).

Here is an example code how to speed things up.

```
procedure TWriterThread.write;
var
  fileLines, memoLines: TStringList;
  i: integer;
  filename: string;
  procedure InternalSynchronize;
  begin
    Synchronize(
      procedure
      begin
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.AddStrings(memoLines);
        SendMessage(Form1.Memo1.Handle, EM_LINESCROLL, 0, Form1.Memo1.Lines.Count); //used to scroll down the memo
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
      end
    );
  end;
begin
  fileLines := TStringList.Create;
  memoLines := TStringList.Create;
  filename := generateFilename;

  try
    for I := 1 to Self.linesToPrint do
    begin

      if i mod 50 = 0 then //Update GUI one per 50 writes.
        InternalSynchronize;

      memoLines.Clear;
      memoLines.Add('Writing: ' + IntToStr(I) + ' to ' + generateFilename);
      fileLines.Add(Format('Line number: %d', [i]));
    end;

    InternalSynchronize;
    fileLines.SaveToFile(filename);
  finally
    fileLines.Free;
    memoLines.Clear;
  end;
end;
```

BTW: if `Memo1` is flickering during update, you might consider to use [DoubleBuffered](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TForm_DoubleBuffered.html) property on a form.

Comment: Don't use DoubleBuffered to paper over the cracks, fix the flickering properly.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think you should "limit max FPS" as they do in 3D games.

I think you do not try to show user some fluent shapes smoothly transforming one into another, instead you want him to see some textual information.

Then you have to give user time to see and read the text.
If you do not - then there is no point to even show it.

So I think you should

1. Set `TTimer` on the form that would update few times per second. In my experience with simple text like "12,5% of the job done" or "123 cells of 4321 processed" the frequency is to be between 2 and 4 re-renderings per second ( `TTimer` delay between 250 and 500 msec ). The more complex your output is - the more time it would take for the human being to read it - the less should be the frequency.
2. The threads should emit the data-to-be-rendered into a special multi-writers/single-reader buffer. For the simple texts like I outlined above Windows Messages are well enough (just don't forget your threads should use `PostMessage` never `SendMessage`). For more complex data I'd suggest you to use `iOmniBlockingCollection` from `OmniThreads Library` - http://otl.17slon.com
3. You `TTimer` event should check for availability of the new data, render it as fast as it can - using `TStrings.BeginUpdate` at `TMemo.Lines` REALLY matters - and remove from the buffer.
4. When process is over, you stop the `TTimer` and issue out of order data/form update.

That way you cap the FPS to remove flickering and that both lets user see anything and frees CPU of meaningless work.

See also my answers to

- [Delphi 7 Occasional deadlock changing TLabel.Font.Style from IdHTTPListener event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119812)
- [NetShareEnum not displaying shares correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293490)